# Tipue search + Jekyll = jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).tipuesearch is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, jekyll

I am trying to make a local JavaScript search option for [this open-source website](http://learn.neurotechedu.com/search/). It's built with Jekyll (Feeling responsive theme) +  [Tipue Search for Jekyll](https://github.com/jekylltools/jekyll-tipue-search).

However, I keep getting:

```
jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).tipuesearch is not a function @http://learn.neurotechedu.com/search/:1:33
```

Its very frustrating, because I feel like i have all files and links in place but the called function is still not connecting with the js file. Could anyone give me a hand?
I'm a noob :(

Comment: Is there some kind of code to make `tipquesearch` jQuery? After typing http://learn.neurotechedu.com/assets/tipuesearch/tipuesearch_content.js in my Browser I see that it's an Object, but not that it's jQuery. I don't know. Just a comment. Nothing there at http://learn.neurotechedu.com/learn.neurotechedu.com/assets/tipuesearch/tipuesearch_content.js.

Answer (score 1):

You do not link to your resource correctly. It is showing a 404 response for multiple assets. So you are trying to reference a function that has not been defined yet.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is from including jQuery twice; once from the google apis like in the Tipque instructions, and once from javascript.min.js. I'd try removing the include of javascript.min.js on this page (since it's jQuery 2.1.1 and you want jQuery 3.2.1 for Tipque search as of this writing) and see if your search works now.